# How to add Spanish elevation data to QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I want to add Spanish Elevation Data to QGIS for use with Profile Tool. "Elevation" search in Plugins gives only some countries, and in QuickMapServices the "Elevation" search gives something other than needed. I also tried SRTM downloader.

I added all the layers I had to profile tool, but it's not clear to me, how to identify that a layer has compatible elevation data. I need some spanish places near Barcelona, and to know how to make Profile Tool aware of them.

Comment: Try Mapzen Global Terrain layer from XYZ Tiles entry in Browser Panel (must have newer QGIS version). Otherwise, download a Digital Elevation Model - maybe have a look at the national topographic atuhority's website or consult https://opendem.info/

Comment: I'm a little bit new to using QGIS, and I'm not sure about how to download map data and connect it to right coordinates. My XYZ Tiles browser contains only OpenStreetMap layer; how to download the right area for Mapzen - is there some plugin or should I download from their website - and add it to there. OpenDEM - does it contain world-wide or spanish data, or just some cities? How to download and add layers to QGIS from these datasets - I only did using some plugins. I have to orient myself in different datasets.

Comment: Update to QGIS 3.26 to get the Mapzen entry in XYZ tiles. If you download a DEM, it should be georeferenced an show up in the correct place on Earth's surface

Comment: Normally download data from a website as a file and than add it to QGIS

Comment: To use the profile tool you need a digital elevation model. These are a raster layer in which each pixel has an elevation value. There are a lot of online reources where you can get them. SRTM data should do it, but they com normally in geographic coordinates, so coordinates will be in decimal degrees and elevation data in meters. You could try to reproject this data to a projected coordinate system (like UTM for instance) to get the extension of your profile in meter and not degrees. Also you can try to get some data from the Spanish National Geographic Institute.

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to update qgis to 3.26 on Ubuntu and Synaptic - the latest version with my sources seems to be 3.22.4. I tried this command line - https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html -, but this could not install anything. Meanwhile, I try with virtualboxes of other linuxes as well and try to add manually this Synaptic source; anyway, it said it could not find and will not install, for different packages.

Comment: I am going to try with this - https://land.copernicus.eu/imagery-in-situ/eu-dem/eu-dem-v1.1/view -; this is Digital Elevation Model over Europe.

Comment: land.copernicus.eu/imagery-in-situ/eu-dem/eu-dem-v1.1/view is fully functional and working DEM database for Europe. I got the Spanish square to work, with QGIS 3.22. Thank you for suggesting the DEM, Gerardo! And thank you for your answers, Babel.